# presented at a conference but don't appear in proceedings

Tags: conference, cv

What's the protocol if you present at a conference but aren't listed on the conference proceedings? As in, my advisor (when I was a doc student) submitted the presentation under her name, but I was asked to join and present. So my name is not attached anywhere, but I was there and presented the work with her. Can I list it on my cv? Or just leave it off and consider it good experience?

Comment: Have you contributed to the paper before attending the conference? Have you presented the paper alone or together with your advisor?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can include it in a special section - Other Contributions. Say what you have said here, but also have in your possession a letter from the author thanking you for presenting the work (or helping to present - whichever is more accurate) and for any contributions you made to it. The backup letter is essential and the classification of the contribution has to be accurate.